# Split column and format the column values

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I am trying to format one column data. I can find options to split the columns as it has `,` in between but I am not able to format it as shown in output.

Input

```
    TITLE,Issn
NATURE REVIEWS MOLECULAR CELL BIOLOGY,"ISSN 14710072, 14710080"
ANNUAL REVIEW OF IMMUNOLOGY,"ISSN 07320582, 15453278"
NATURE REVIEWS GENETICS,"ISSN 14710056, 14710064"
CA - A CANCER JOURNAL FOR CLINICIANS,"ISSN 15424863, 00079235"
CELL,"ISSN 00928674, 10974172"
ANNUAL REVIEW OF ASTRONOMY AND ASTROPHYSICS,"ISSN 15454282, 00664146"
NATURE REVIEWS IMMUNOLOGY,"ISSN 14741741, 14741733"
NATURE REVIEWS CANCER,ISSN 1474175X
ANNUAL REVIEW OF BIOCHEMISTRY,"ISSN 15454509, 00664154"
REVIEWS OF MODERN PHYSICS,"ISSN 00346861, 15390756"
NATURE GENETICS,ISSN 10614036
```

1. Split the issn column to two columns as it has `,`
2. Delete the word ISSN from column only
3. leave behind numbers  After 4 digits put a `-`

Expected output is

```
    TITLE,Issn
NATURE REVIEWS MOLECULAR CELL BIOLOGY,1471-0072, 1471-0080
ANNUAL REVIEW OF IMMUNOLOGY,0732-0582, 1545-3278
NATURE REVIEWS GENETICS,1471-0056, 1471-0064
CA - A CANCER JOURNAL FOR CLINICIANS,1542-4863, 0007-9235
CELL,0092-8674, 1097-4172
ANNUAL REVIEW OF ASTRONOMY AND ASTROPHYSICS,1545-4282, 0066-4146
NATURE REVIEWS IMMUNOLOGY,1474-1741, 1474-1733
NATURE REVIEWS CANCER, 1474-175X
ANNUAL REVIEW OF BIOCHEMISTRY,1545-4509, 0066-4154
REVIEWS OF MODERN PHYSICS,0034-6861, 1539-0756
NATURE GENETICS,1061-4036
```

Any suggestion with pandas are appreciated .. Thanks in advance

**Update:**
When trying to run both the programs as mentioned in answer

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.read_csv('new_journal_list.csv', header='TITLE,Issn')

'''
df_split_num = df['Issn'].map(lambda x: x.split('ISSN ')[1].split(', '))
df_dash_num = df_split_num.map(lambda x: [num[:4] + '-' + num[4:] for num in x])

df_split_issn = pd.DataFrame(data=list(df_dash_num), columns=['Issn1', 'Issn2'])
df[['Issn1', 'Issn2']] = df_split_issn
del df['Issn']

print df

'''

df[['Issn1','Issn2']] = (df.pop('Issn').str.extract('ISSN\s+([^,]+),?\s?(.*)', expand=True)
                   .apply(lambda x: x.str[:4]+'-'+x.str[4:]).replace(r'^-$', '', regex=True))

print df
```

Either cases when run in default python 2.7 I am getting following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "clean_journal_list.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from pandas import hashtable, tslib, lib
  File "pandas/src/numpy.pxd", line 157, in init pandas.hashtable (pandas/hashtable.c:38364)
```

When run in python 3.4 the below given error is seen

```
File "clean_journal_list.py", line 21
    print df
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: could you post your data as output of `print(df.to_csv())` - because it's difficult to parse it...

Comment: Yes I can .. ..

Comment: @MaxU Done changing the input to csv ..

Comment: Change: `print df` --> `print(df)` for Python 3.x

Comment: Yes I did ..Thanks again ..

Comment: I guess you would have to reinstall numpy and pandas for your Python 2.7 installation - they seem to be broken

Comment: @MaxU I had to install python 3.4 for another execution and when the print statement is changed for python3 it says pandas not found so had to upgrade pandas in default environment and execute in python 2.7 ..

Comment: Python 2.7 also supports `print()` function

Comment: Yes It did .. May be it was Pandas which was broke .. But in when I am having python 3.x along with 2.7 and I am trying to execute in `python3` I am getting error

Comment: @MaxU `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "clean_journal_list.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ImportError: No module named 'pandas'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, split out numbers and add dashes to them. Use the handy map function:

```
df_split_num = df['Issn'].map(lambda x: x.split('ISSN ')[1].split(', '))
df_dash_num = df_split_num.map(lambda x: [num[:4] + '-' + num[4:] for num in x])
```

Next, create a new data frame with the split out issn numbers and place it back into the original data frame:

```
df_split_issn = pd.DataFrame(data=list(df_dash_num), columns=['Issn1', 'Issn2'])
df[['Issn1', 'Issn2']] = df_split_issn
del df['Issn']
```

Comment: could you please check the updated input and output.. Rank is no more a column

Comment: I'm assuming your input is a dataframe. If Rank is not an index, you would just need to drop reset_index and set_index lines above.

Comment: Thank you so much .. but I have no doubt will it effect the order of the values in the column ? Coz these are ISSN numbers of the Journal Titles from first column ?

Comment: one last thing .. i'll be printing the same `df` which i read right ?

Answer (score 2):

IIUC you can do it using [Series.str.extract()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html), `apply()` and `replace()` methods:

```
In [33]: df
Out[33]:
                                          TITLE                     Issn
0         NATURE REVIEWS MOLECULAR CELL BIOLOGY  ISSN 14710072, 14710080
1                   ANNUAL REVIEW OF IMMUNOLOGY  ISSN 07320582, 15453278
2                       NATURE REVIEWS GENETICS  ISSN 14710056, 14710064
3          CA - A CANCER JOURNAL FOR CLINICIANS  ISSN 15424863, 00079235
4                                          CELL  ISSN 00928674, 10974172
5   ANNUAL REVIEW OF ASTRONOMY AND ASTROPHYSICS  ISSN 15454282, 00664146
6                     NATURE REVIEWS IMMUNOLOGY  ISSN 14741741, 14741733
7                         NATURE REVIEWS CANCER            ISSN 1474175X
8                 ANNUAL REVIEW OF BIOCHEMISTRY  ISSN 15454509, 00664154
9                     REVIEWS OF MODERN PHYSICS  ISSN 00346861, 15390756
10                              NATURE GENETICS            ISSN 10614036

In [34]: df[['Issn1','Issn2']] = (df.pop('Issn')
    ...:                            .str.extract('ISSN\s+([^,]+),?\s?(.*)', expand=True)
    ...:                            .apply(lambda x: x.str[:4]+'-'+x.str[4:])
    ...:                            .replace(r'^-$', '', regex=True))
    ...:

In [35]: df
Out[35]:
                                          TITLE      Issn1      Issn2
0         NATURE REVIEWS MOLECULAR CELL BIOLOGY  1471-0072  1471-0080
1                   ANNUAL REVIEW OF IMMUNOLOGY  0732-0582  1545-3278
2                       NATURE REVIEWS GENETICS  1471-0056  1471-0064
3          CA - A CANCER JOURNAL FOR CLINICIANS  1542-4863  0007-9235
4                                          CELL  0092-8674  1097-4172
5   ANNUAL REVIEW OF ASTRONOMY AND ASTROPHYSICS  1545-4282  0066-4146
6                     NATURE REVIEWS IMMUNOLOGY  1474-1741  1474-1733
7                         NATURE REVIEWS CANCER  1474-175X
8                 ANNUAL REVIEW OF BIOCHEMISTRY  1545-4509  0066-4154
9                     REVIEWS OF MODERN PHYSICS  0034-6861  1539-0756
10                              NATURE GENETICS  1061-4036
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to add some error handling to this, and wrap it in a line-by-line iteration, but here's the gist of it:

```
leader, issns = line.split(" ISSN ")
numbers = issns.split(", ")

print leader, ', '.join([ num[:4] + '-' + num[4:] for num in numbers])
```

The key thing is to split each line into "the ISSN numbers" and "everything else", then separate the ISSN numbers from each other and reformat them.